# Reactjs Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '.png' when loading from a json file

Tags: reactjs, json, image, require

i'm trying to load some images whose path is stored inside a JSON file, in reactjs. My JSON file contains an array of objects in which there is the path of my images. Inside my component, i map my JSON data and can access every properties. Nevertheless, when i try to load the image, it keeps showing me the same error : Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '.png'  when loading from a json file.
Where i'm trying to load the image
[image: loading image]

My JSON file
[image: JSON file]

I've added the import of my json file at the beginning of my file

```
import projects from "../data/importantProject.json"
```

The error
[image: error]

Has anyone experienced the same issue ?

I tried to add a based url, and a "" as I saw on the web but it keeps showing me the same error.

Comment: You should add your code as text rather than screenshots!

Answer (score 1):

1 ----> In json file instead of full file path just write the file name **ie : fap_logo.png**

2 ----> In  react component write **<img src={require(`../assets/images/`+project.logo)} alt="image" />**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your image src as:

```
const imgsrc = require("../assets/images/"  +project.logo).default;
```

Note at 'default' at the end of the require method:

require(filepath).**default**